Correlation power analysis of AES hardware implementation
In software, finding the outputs of the s-boxes is easier because these values would need to be loaded from memory onto a high-capacitance data bus.
On hardware, the output of the s-boxes may be directly fed into the next stage of the algorithm.
With a hardware implementation, it's often possible to not only combine basic operations into a block that can run in a single clock cycle, but also combine multiple AES operations and run them in a single block. Even a whole AES round.
How to perform AES CPA on such a hardware implementation of AES, assuming it is basic implementation without any additional countermeasures (sbox shuffling etc.)?
